# exceptions.TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable with nested JSON list

Tags: python, json, list, nested-lists

I have a JSON object returned via an XHR request that takes the following format:

```
[[[13, u'Arsenal', [[[[u'goal', u'openplay', u'header', [1]], [u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', 
[1]], [u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [3]], [u'goal', u'owngoal', u'rightfoot', [1]], [u'miss', 
u'corner', u'header', [2]], [u'miss', u'corner', u'leftfoot', [3]], [u'miss', u'corner', u'rightfoot',
[2]], [u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'rightfoot', [2]], [u'miss', u'directfreekick', u'leftfoot', [1]],
[u'miss', u'openplay', u'header', [2]], [u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot', [16]], [u'miss', 
u'openplay', u'rightfoot', [23]]]]]]
```

Where `responser`is the JSON object above, I have used the following code to convert this nested list into a Python dictionary with tuples for the dictionary keys:

```
 for match in responser: 
                    for num_events, team, events in match:

                        regex = {tuple(sub[:3]): sub[3][0] for y in events[0] for sub in y}
```

However, when I try and use the same object on the below nested list:

```
    [[[13, u'Arsenal', [[6.125, [[u'assist', u'cross', [3]], [u'normal', u'cross', [198]], [u'normal',
 u'longball', [326]], [u'assist', u'short', [5]], [u'normal', u'short', [4726]], [u'assist', 
u'throughball', [1]], [u'normal', u'throughball', [35]]]]]]
```

I get the following error:

```
exceptions.TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I can see that the JSON nested list in the second example is slightly different in structure to the first, but I am not sure how to amend my code to accommodate this, or specifically why I am getting this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `6.125` value: your code doesn't account for it being there. Also each minilist has 2 items instead of 3 and the code needs to be adjusted accordingly.

The only way I could get it to work was to break it down into pieces. You don't want to cram too many things into a list/dictionary comprehension:

This is my code to convert the first list:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for a in responser[2][0][0]:
...   d.update({tuple(a[:3]): a[3][0]})
```

And this is my code to convert the second list. The "1" is to get the item after the 6.125 value. And the "3" elements is changed to "2":

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for a in responser[2][0][1]:
...   d.update({tuple(a[:2]): a[2][0]})
...
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. this answer gives me an error message that the index is out of range.

Comment: please note i have amended my answer, as my json object contained a typo where there were not enough opening brackets at the start of the object. i'm not sure if that would have effected your answer though?

Comment: hmm, actually it was working for me before but now there are not enough closing brackets. You can try this site to see if it's valid or not. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ (Remove the u's, change ' to ", and remove carriage returns first.)